# Moderator-Designated Question-Asking Hints

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, moderator-tools

It would be nice to have a section on the Ask Question page that allows a custom, site-specific hint that moderators can edit, just to give new (or even returning) users a quick hint or reminder of what information is useful to have in most questions.

For example, I'm a moderator on [Startups](http://startups.stackexchange.com), and we receive a lot of questions that pertain to legal issues, the answers to which tend to vary greatly depending on the location. So we might want something like this:

[image: Example image]

For us at Startups, we see a lot of even experienced users who forget to post a location, and that can lead to some outdated, or worse, dangerously inaccurate, answers. It would be useful to remind the asker at the time of asking to include details.

On Software Recs (and I certainly don't mean to speak on their behalf, this is just an example), they might want something like "try and include specific details about the software you're looking for, especially a specific use-scenario for it." On Stack Overflow, perhaps "remember to include specifics of what you've already tried in your question, if relevant." I'm sure mods on most sites could think of a quick tidbit they'd like to mention in such a message.

They probably wouldn't say much more than what [help/on-topic](/help-on-topic) already does, but if moderators could be given five hundred characters (with comment markdown enabled) to include the very basics and catch the cases that they see a lot, that could be helpful.

I view this as a constant, similar to VTC reasons, but it could be expanded to cover "show this hint when this tag is present" cues, but I don't think that'd be necessary, especially to start.

It certainly wouldn't be foolproof, and some users would probably become blind to it pretty quickly. But at least it could help a number of cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tips/hints based on tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105838/tips-hints-based-on-tags)

Comment: @random I'm not talking about the presence of tags, in fact specifically the opposite--I just want something that's statically present regardless of tags, and they should be present about the *site*, rather than about the tags.

Comment: I guess to be perfectly clear, as we encounter our third VTC as a duplicate of that, I an *not* suggesting that we display hints based on tags. I am suggesting that we display hints *about how to ask a question*. My specific example *happened* to include a suggestion of something to tag, but note that it, even, was not based on preexisting tags, and is a site-wide matter. I only included the `Tags` textbox, if that's the source of confusion, to present scope or context of what I was talking about, it is not related in any way to my question, any more than any other feature of that page.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164929/change-how-to-tag-and-or-move-it-for-visibility para 3,4

Comment: And the why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94406/why-do-people-fail-at-tagging-and-what-to-do-about-it

Comment: This sounds exactly like the vote to close system.

Answer (score 6):

This is going to be useful on other sites too. Just in terms of tagging advice, there are other sites which have important categories of tags it may not occur to the user to add:

- On [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) and [Personal Finance & Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/), country tags are also desired very often when the jurisdiction or location can matter.
- On [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) we would use this to remind people to tag with the system they're playing, and that if they're using D&D, please tag with the version in question (e.g. [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) for the latest version). This is because a few times a month we'll get a question that doesn't include a tag for the RPG system, and it's *usually* a D&D question. Or we'll get a D&D question that just uses our generic [dungeons-and-dragons](/questions/tagged/dungeons-and-dragons) tag.